# Draw editview / textview on fingertouch in Android

Tags: android

I am newbie in Android, in my app I required draw textview/editview on finger touch where user is able to type in that.I searched a lot but find nothing relevant.

I found links to draw editview/text but not on fingertouch.

Comment: What do you mean, "fingertouch"?  Do you mean that you want the keyboard to popup when the user touches the textview?

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by registering touch events on a view. And when the touch event fires, you can then create a EditText/TextView based on the touch event coordinates.

```
class YourMainClass extends Activity{

  public void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
  {
     //Do your normal UI initialization here
     your_layout.setOnTouchListener(new TouchListener()); //where your_layout is the layout/view of your Activity that should register the touch events.
  }

  class TouchListener implements OnTouchListener
  {
     @Override
     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
         if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
           RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); //See note below
           params.leftMargin = (int)event.getX() - v.getLeft();
           params.topMargin = (int)event.getY() - v.getTop();
           EditText edit = new EditText(this);
           edit.setLayoutParams(params);
           your_layout.addView(edit);
           return true;
         }
     }
  }
}
```

Note: Be sure to change the LayoutParams type to the type of layout you use (for example: LinearLayout.LayoutParams if you're using a LinearLayout to place the EditText in).

Also if you use padding, the coordinates of the actual EditText might be off (since the padding area is still counted as the View when using `v.getLeft()` and `v.getTop()`, but not when adding the EditText to your layout).

Comment: No problem. If the above example worked, please be sure to upvote/accept it so more people will see it :)